# Did Meruem propose to Komugi by asking her to hold his hand?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

I was reading on a forum that the author/mangaka of the "Hunter x Hunter" series was trying to "tell" the readers that Meruem asked Komugi to be his wife by telling her to hold his hand. Is it true? Or he was just afraid to die alone, with the hand of Komugi making him feel safer (or at least that's what I understood from that scene)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that Meruem never had any romantic feelings for Kogumi. What he felt was awe and maybe some admiration because:

1) She was a the weakest frail human he had ever seen. She was even blind and unable to take care of herself.
2) Yet she beat him everytime they played. 
3) She wasn't afraid of him. She treated him like any other person.

She was someone precious to him in that regard (her caring nature mighr have played a part in it too)